# How to install xcode in windows 10?

Tags: xcode, windows

Is it possible to download Xcode in windows guys? can you give me some good links in details on how to install it?

thanks.

Comment: You can google hackintosh and see if you can install OSX on your PC

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is produced by Apple for Apple hardware, so you are out of luck.

When Swift is open sourced, you'll probably be able to use it with the various IDE's which are out there.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to get XCode to  run in windows 10 is to create a virtual machine for OS X inside of your windows 10 OS.  This can be done via VirtualBox, which is free.  Now unfortunately,  since it is VM,  it is going to run a lot slower than if it was on its native OS,  so I would not recommend going this route unless you have a really good machine, so your better options are looking into hackintosh's, or actual Apple hardware.  I myself recommend actual Apple hardware because things go wrong all the time with hackintosh's whenever Apple updates

Comment: Modern processors provide hardware virtualization features (Intel's VT-x and AMD's AMD-V), allowing virtual machines to operate at near native performance. This is not an issue. However, installing OS X in a VM is not covered by Apple's EULA.

Comment: This mostly pertains to the CPU,  GPUs have there own virtualization technologies that need to also be considered, among other things.  And Apple allows for El Capitan to be installed on 2 VM's when it meets certain criteria, which I will not get into, that is what the EULA is for